# Grabing data from both API and SQL database

Tags: sql, xml, json, api, twitter

I'm building a Twitter Application to show specific tweets (that matching pre defined criteria). I used a good library to grab the tweets and before showing them to the user I the tweets must get stored in a local database, so that I have more data and amazing statistics (ego? huh) to be calculated and shown to the user.

The problem is that tweets are not stored in the hashtag, so if I search for the hashtag one week later I will not be able to find the tweets, so I must have a way to show the tweets from the database instead of Twitter API. I decided that I will show data from database when the last tweet from a hashtag (in the database) is stored before than three days or more. when the last tweet is stored in less than three days, then I will ask Twitter to show the tweets.

So I'm asking you if you have an idea how to show tweets from database since my library depends on JSON (or consider it XML). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Store the tweets in CouchDB. If you use twitter streaming api or search api, that should be the most straightforward way for "saving" tweets.

Comment: Ok, Will I be able to save and retrieve tweets as json format through this database ?

Comment: JSON format is the default storing type for CouchDB. Both `inserts` made by `curl -X PUT http://dbhost:5984/mydb/UUID` and `retrieval` made by `curl -X GET http://dbhost:5984/mydb/UUID` are done by passing/getting the data in JSON format. Be sure to read http://guide.couchdb.org before you start investigating.